# Can I start Tomcat with my domain certificate?

Tags: tomcat, ssl

This question might be a really dumb but the whole certificate stuff is very complicated for me.

A certain feature requires a signed certificate which is not self signed. Now I need to test the feature and I wonder if this is possible and how I do it.

My idea is to start my Tomcat server with our domain certificate (it's the .crt file) and then edit the hosts file to point the domain to localhost so when I open domain.com in the browser it requests localhost and uses the domain.com certificate. Is this possible?

I have already imported the certificate into the local keystore with

```
"$JAVA_HOME"/bin/keytool.exe -import -trustcacerts -alias tomcat -file mycert.crt
```

However when I start the server I get this exception:

```
Alias name [tomcat] does not identify a key entry
```

I think the reason for this is that it is a `trustedCertEntry` and there is no private key file.

Edit: Let's assume I have a `pem` file with my certificate, an intermediate certificate and a private key. What do I need to do to load this into the keystore?

Comment: **Exactly**; you created a trustedCert entry containing only a cert but **SSL/TLS server needs a privatekey entry** that contains the privateKey AND related cert AND usually chain/intermediate cert(s) also. If you have the privatekey in PEM (e.g. from httpd or nginx) there are dozens of existing Qs on how to convert to PKCS12 and thence to JKS if needed, or Tomcat 8.5 up can now use PEM key&certs directly if you look at its documentation. If you have the key in some other form there are probably options but you need to specify what you have.

Comment: With this I was able to import the certificates. https://serverfault.com/a/745143